# Hide mobile menu when clicking on a link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to hide my mobile menu when an anchor link is clicked.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55583967/collapse-hide-mobile-nav-menu-after-nav-link-click)

```
$(function () { 
   $('#menu-main li>a').on('click', function (e) {
       $( "#menu-toggle" ).click();
   });
});
```

solution which looked promising but I couldn't quite get it to work (I probably did something wrong)

I also tried implementing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58471859/close-mobile-menu-when-clicking-link-in-hid) solution

```
function onLinkClick() {
  var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("hamburger");
  coll.classList.remove("active");
}
```

but probably did something wrong here as well

My code:

```js
let burger = document.getElementById('burger'),
     nav    = document.getElementById('main-nav'),
     slowmo = document.getElementById('slowmo');
   
burger.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    this.classList.toggle('is-open');
    nav.classList.toggle('is-open');
});
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: helvetica;
}

body {
  height: 2000px;
}

#wrap {
  scroll-margin-top: 130px;
}

button {
cursor: pointer;
}

.main-nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba (0,0,0,0);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all .375s;
}

.main-nav.is-open {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1100;
    visibility: visible;
}

/* Yellow band effect */
.main-nav::before {
     content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: -15px;
    background: #fff;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: skew(-14deg) translateX(-120%);
    transition: all .275s .1s;
}

.main-nav.is-open::before {
    transform: skew(-14deg) translateX(0);
}

/* Skewing effect on menu links */
.main-nav ul {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 93%; /* Should be 100%, but we have a notice message :D */
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: center;
    transform: translateX(-18%) skew(-16deg);
}

.main-nav li {
    display: block;
    margin: .5rem 0;
    text-align: right;
    transform: skew(16deg);
}

/* Apparition effect on links */
.main-nav button {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.main-nav.is-open button {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
}
.main-nav li:nth-child(1) a {
    transition: all 275ms 175ms
}
.main-nav li:nth-child(2) a {
    transition: all 275ms 225ms
}
.main-nav li:nth-child(3) a {
    transition: all 275ms 275ms
}
.main-nav li:nth-child(4) a {
    transition: all 275ms 325ms
}
.main-nav li:nth-child(5) a {
    transition: all 275ms 375ms
}


/* Decoration */
.main-nav ul,
.main-nav li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
.main-nav button {
    display: block;
    padding: 12px 0;
    color: #5A3B5D;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* Burger Style: @see: https://codepen.io/CreativeJuiz/full/oMZNXy */
.open-main-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    right: 15px;
    z-index: 1200;
    background: none;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.open-main-nav:focus {
    outline: none;
}
#burger {
  position: fixed;
  float: right;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.burger {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 28px;
    height: 4px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
    transform: skew(5deg);
    transition: all .275s;
  margin-top: 1vw;
}

.burger:after,
.burger:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    transition: all .275s;
}

#burger.shrink .burger {
    background: #000 !important;
  margin-top: 0.7vw;
}

#burger.shrink .burger:after {
    background: #000 !important;
}

#burger.shrink .burger:before {
  background: #000 !important;
}

.burger:after {
    transform: translateY(-12px) translateX(-2px) skew(-20deg);
}

.burger:before {
    transform: translateY(-16px) skew(-10deg);
}

/* Toggle State part */
.is-open .burger {
    transform: skew(5deg) translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.is-open .burger:before {
    transform: translateY(0px) skew(-10deg) rotate(75deg);
}

.is-open .burger:after {
    transform: translateY(-12px) translateX(10px) skew(-20deg);
    opacity: 0;
}

.is-open .burger, .is-open .burger:after, .is-open .burger:before {
  background: #000;
}

/* MENU Text part */

.burger-text {
    display: block;
    font-size: .675rem;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
    margin-top: .5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}

#burger.shrink .burger-text {
  color: #000;
}
.is-open .burger-text {
  color: #000;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    bottom: 0; left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Notice */
.notice {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -15px;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #F2F2F2;
    color: #5A3B5D;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    z-index: 100;
    text-align: center;
}
.notice strong {
    font-weight: 700;
}
.notice button {
    padding: 2px 3px;
    background: #FEDC2A;
    text-decoration: none;
}



h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 8vw;
  top: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 3em;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-table;
  margin-left: -1.5em;
  padding-left: -1.5em;
}

#wrap {
  scroll-margin-top: 80px;
}

#burger {
  visibility: visible;
}

.navb {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  color: #87CEEB !important;
  font-size: 0.6rem;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.navb:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
}

#navbar {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  z-index: 999;
  transition: 0.3s;
  line-height: 18px;
}

#navwrapper {
  background: linear-gradient(250deg, #0061ff, #60efff);
  background-size: 400% 400%;

  -webkit-animation: AnimationName 10s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: AnimationName 10s ease infinite;
  animation: AnimationName 10s ease infinite;
  height: 100vh;
}

@-webkit-keyframes AnimationName {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 7%
  }

  50% {
    background-position: 100% 94%
  }

  100% {
    background-position: 0% 7%
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes AnimationName {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 7%
  }

  50% {
    background-position: 100% 94%
  }

  100% {
    background-position: 0% 7%
  }
}

@keyframes AnimationName {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 7%
  }

  50% {
    background-position: 100% 94%
  }

  100% {
    background-position: 0% 7%
  }
}

.selectSection {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.selectSection button {
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px;
  outline: none;
}


.activenav {
  color: black !important;
}

.mobilecontainer {
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

```html
    <head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!--<script src="assets/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
    </head>
  <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
  <body>
    <nav id="navwrapper">      
        <button id="burger" class="open-main-nav">
            <span class="burger"></span>
            <span class="burger-text">Menu</span>
        </button>
    <div class="mobilecontainer navbar navbar-dark bg-primary navbar-fixed-top selectSection">
        <div class="main-nav" id="main-nav">
            <ul>
          <li class="nav-item"><button onclick="location.href='#wrap'" class="activenav mobilenavb">content1</button></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
</div>
    </nav>
    
     <div id="wrap" class="contentSection wrapper">
        <div>
          <h1>content1</h1>
          <h2>lorem ipsum</h2>
        </div>
```

Note that I'm just a beginner and haven't played much around in JS so it's very easy for me to overlook something or just simply doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, you've added Jquery library. Simply adding click listener for every `nav-item` class.

For example:

```
$(".nav-item").click(function(){
  burger.click();
})
```

```js
let burger = document.getElementById('burger'),
     nav    = document.getElementById('main-nav'),
     slowmo = document.getElementById('slowmo');
   
burger.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    this.classList.toggle('is-open');
    nav.classList.toggle('is-open');
});

$(".nav-item").click(function(){
  burger.click();
})
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: helvetica;
}

body {
  height: 2000px;
}

#wrap {
  scroll-margin-top: 130px;
}

button {
cursor: pointer;
}

.main-nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba (0,0,0,0);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all .375s;
}

.main-nav.is-open {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1100;
    visibility: visible;
}

/* Yellow band effect */
.main-nav::before {
     content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: -15px;
    background: #fff;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: skew(-14deg) translateX(-120%);
    transition: all .275s .1s;
}

.main-nav.is-open::before {
    transform: skew(-14deg) translateX(0);
}

/* Skewing effect on menu links */
.main-nav ul {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 93%; /* Should be 100%, but we have a notice message :D */
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: center;
    transform: translateX(-18%) skew(-16deg);
}

.main-nav li {
    display: block;
    margin: .5rem 0;
    text-align: right;
    transform: skew(16deg);
}

/* Apparition effect on links */
.main-nav button {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.main-nav.is-open button {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
}
.main-nav li:nth-child(1) a {
    transition: all 275ms 175ms
}
.main-nav li:nth-child(2) a {
    transition: all 275ms 225ms
}
.main-nav li:nth-child(3) a {
    transition: all 275ms 275ms
}
.main-nav li:nth-child(4) a {
    transition: all 275ms 325ms
}
.main-nav li:nth-child(5) a {
    transition: all 275ms 375ms
}


/* Decoration */
.main-nav ul,
.main-nav li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
.main-nav button {
    display: block;
    padding: 12px 0;
    color: #5A3B5D;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* Burger Style: @see: https://codepen.io/CreativeJuiz/full/oMZNXy */
.open-main-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    right: 15px;
    z-index: 1200;
    background: none;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.open-main-nav:focus {
    outline: none;
}
#burger {
  position: fixed;
  float: right;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.burger {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 28px;
    height: 4px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
    transform: skew(5deg);
    transition: all .275s;
  margin-top: 1vw;
}

.burger:after,
.burger:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    transition: all .275s;
}

#burger.shrink .burger {
    background: #000 !important;
  margin-top: 0.7vw;
}

#burger.shrink .burger:after {
    background: #000 !important;
}

#burger.shrink .burger:before {
  background: #000 !important;
}

.burger:after {
    transform: translateY(-12px) translateX(-2px) skew(-20deg);
}

.burger:before {
    transform: translateY(-16px) skew(-10deg);
}

/* Toggle State part */
.is-open .burger {
    transform: skew(5deg) translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.is-open .burger:before {
    transform: translateY(0px) skew(-10deg) rotate(75deg);
}

.is-open .burger:after {
    transform: translateY(-12px) translateX(10px) skew(-20deg);
    opacity: 0;
}

.is-open .burger, .is-open .burger:after, .is-open .burger:before {
  background: #000;
}

/* MENU Text part */

.burger-text {
    display: block;
    font-size: .675rem;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
    margin-top: .5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}

#burger.shrink .burger-text {
  color: #000;
}
.is-open .burger-text {
  color: #000;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    bottom: 0; left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Notice */
.notice {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -15px;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #F2F2F2;
    color: #5A3B5D;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    z-index: 100;
    text-align: center;
}
.notice strong {
    font-weight: 700;
}
.notice button {
    padding: 2px 3px;
    background: #FEDC2A;
    text-decoration: none;
}



h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 8vw;
  top: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 3em;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-table;
  margin-left: -1.5em;
  padding-left: -1.5em;
}

#wrap {
  scroll-margin-top: 80px;
}

#burger {
  visibility: visible;
}

.navb {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  color: #87CEEB !important;
  font-size: 0.6rem;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.navb:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
}

#navbar {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  z-index: 999;
  transition: 0.3s;
  line-height: 18px;
}

#navwrapper {
  background: linear-gradient(250deg, #0061ff, #60efff);
  background-size: 400% 400%;

  -webkit-animation: AnimationName 10s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: AnimationName 10s ease infinite;
  animation: AnimationName 10s ease infinite;
  height: 100vh;
}

@-webkit-keyframes AnimationName {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 7%
  }

  50% {
    background-position: 100% 94%
  }

  100% {
    background-position: 0% 7%
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes AnimationName {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 7%
  }

  50% {
    background-position: 100% 94%
  }

  100% {
    background-position: 0% 7%
  }
}

@keyframes AnimationName {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 7%
  }

  50% {
    background-position: 100% 94%
  }

  100% {
    background-position: 0% 7%
  }
}

.selectSection {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.selectSection button {
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px;
  outline: none;
}


.activenav {
  color: black !important;
}

.mobilecontainer {
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

```html
    <head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!--<script src="assets/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
    </head>
  <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
  <body>
    <nav id="navwrapper">      
        <button id="burger" class="open-main-nav">
            <span class="burger"></span>
            <span class="burger-text">Menu</span>
        </button>
    <div class="mobilecontainer navbar navbar-dark bg-primary navbar-fixed-top selectSection">
        <div class="main-nav" id="main-nav">
            <ul>
          <li class="nav-item"><button onclick="location.href='#wrap'" class="activenav mobilenavb">content1</button></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
</div>
    </nav>
    
     <div id="wrap" class="contentSection wrapper">
        <div>
          <h1>content1</h1>
          <h2>lorem ipsum</h2>
        </div>
```